# Having problem in doing operations on values after asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Here i'm calculation two values color and number after calculation i'm updating the values but this is not working

```
gameSchema.methods.computeBets = async function(){
const game = this;
const greenMultiplier = 2;
const voiletMultiplier = 4.5;
const redMultiplier = 2;
try {
    const { gameType } = game;
    let model = Schema;
    gameType === 'Fast Parity' ? model = FastParity : model = SlowParity;
    const gameDetails = await model.findOne({ gameId: game._id });
    const { allPlayerBettedBetId } = gameDetails;

    let color = {};
    let number = {};
    await Promise.all(allPlayerBettedBetId.map(async(bet) => {
        const betdetails = await UserBet.findById(bet._id);
        const { colorBettedOn, numberBettedOn,amountBetted,betType} = betdetails;
        // console.log(colorBettedOn, numberBettedOn, amountBetted);
        if(betType==='color')
            color[colorBettedOn] = color[colorBettedOn] ? color[colorBettedOn] + amountBetted : amountBetted;
        if(betType==='number')
            number[numberBettedOn] = number[numberBettedOn] ? number[numberBettedOn] + amountBetted : amountBetted;
    }));

    console.log(color, number);

    color.forEach(item => {
        if (item.green)
            item.green *= greenMultiplier;
        if (item.red)
            item.red *= redMultiplier;
        if (item.voilet)
            item.voilet *= voiletMultiplier;
    });
    let colorCombination = {
        "green": color.green,
        "green/voilet": color.green+(color.voilet/2),
        "red/voilet": color.red+(color.voilet/2),
        "red": color.red
    };
    number.forEach(item => {
        item.value *= 2;
    })

    console.log(number,colorCombination)

    return { number, colorCombination };
```

after await Promise.all console.log(number,color) is working but when i'm updating the values they are not working.I'm not good at async function as i don't have much exprience in that.what mistake i'm doing in the forEach functions

Comment: Please be more precise than "*it's not working*". What error are you getting?

Comment: "*what mistake i'm doing in the forEach functions*" - the mistake appears to be using `forEach` at all? `color` and `number` are plain objects with numeric properties, they don't have any `forEach` method.

Comment: console.log(number,colorCombination) is not working

Comment: But you just wrote "*after await Promise.all console.log(number,color) is working*"?!

Comment: but after that i'm doing some operation on number and color and then consle.log(number,color) again

Comment: @Bergi thanks i'm using object.entries(color) now or there are other options also